# Filter values from an array of object

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am working on the autocomplete angular material 2 functionality. 
This is the working plunker provided by their site:https://plnkr.co/edit/7Q0zVT68CSPz4wGhFbPo?p=preview

They are filtering the state from a states array. 
This is their filter implementation:

```ts
filterStates(val: string) {
    return val ? this.states.filter(s => new RegExp(`^${val}`, 'gi').test(s))
               : this.states;
  }
```

Currently what they are filtering is an array like this:

```ts
states = [
    'Alabama',
    'Alaska',
    'Arizona',
    'Arkansas',
    'California',
```

'Colorado'
}

However what if it isn't a simple array and is an array of object like:

```ts
states=[{"name":"Alaska",code:1234},
{"name":"Bulgaria",code:12345},
{"name":"Colarado",code:12346},
{"name":"New Jersey",code:12347},
]
```

What I have tried so far is this:

```ts
filterStates(val: string) {
    return val ? this.stateFilter(val)
               : this.states;
  }
statefilteredvalue:string;
  statefilter(val):string{
        for(var i=0; i< this.states.length;i++){
            console.log(this.states[i].name);
           this.statefilteredvalue= this.states[i].name.filter(s => new RegExp(`^${val}`, 'gi').test(s))
        }
        return this.statefilteredvalue;
  }
```

But I do not get the desired output.

How do I filter it based on `name` in the above array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only change you need to make to the original filter, is to change that it will test the regex against the name property of you object, so your `filterStates` should look like this:

```ts
filterStates(val: string) {
  console.log(val)
    return val ? this.states.filter(s => new RegExp(`^${val}`, 'gi').test(s.name))
               : this.states;
}
```

**Update**: You also need to change the `[value]="state"` to `[value]="state.name"`

### [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UuBfH4ylygkSrvhPQQ23?p=preview)

Comment: But as soon as I select something I get an [object object]. And on clearing the fields, I dont see any dropdown.

Comment: Updated answer, was missing one detail. Sorry for the mistake, it should work now (Plunker at least works) :)

Comment: One more thing AJT if you can help me with?

Comment: Sure, what is it and let's see if I can help :)

Comment: Please have a look at this plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/Pf2pWeUYo2mt7VzwCDs2?p=preview. It has state names changed slightly. After selecting one state when I try to delete it with backspace i get error on console and also do not get the dropdown afterwards.

Comment: This is a problem with the regexp. It doesn't like the parenthesis in the name... so if you try typing `A, l, a, s, k, a, space key, (` it will throw the error as well after typing the parenthesis. I'm no expert on regexp, but you need to have a regexp that accepts parenthesis.

Comment: Right that was what I was thinking. Thanks for looking into it. I guess I just need to open a new thread for it on SO.

Comment: Yes I suggest you do, I would love to help you, but as said it's not something I'm an expert on. Remember to tag regexp and javascript in that question, so it can reach people that are very good at regular expressions! :)

Comment: Thanx again man. You seem to be a gentlemen when it comes to helping on SO.